# jQuery swap logo when clicking a link and reaching a certain page section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap based layout to build a website. It can be accessed here: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-grayscale/

Instead of the text-based logo I'm using a image. Is there any way to swap the image with another one when a section of the menu is clicked on? for example I want the logo to swap when you click on about and slide to that section.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementById(element).src` to change the image source of the logo you're using as demonstrated in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm4aomzm/) (this is a javascript solution).

If you must use jQuery, you can use `.attr()` to change the source. For example:
`$(element).attr("src","otherImage.jpg");`